# Is the inverse relation of a multiary algebraic function a multivalued function, or a set-valued function?

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

A multiary function is a function $X_1\times X_2\times ...\times X_n\rightarrow Y$, with $n>1$.

Is the inverse relation of a multiary algebraic function a multivalued function, or is it a set-valued function?

A multivalued function is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse relation of a multiary algebraic function is a multivalued function. But a multivalued function is not a function. "Multivalued function" is a misnomer because a function can be only one-to-one or many-to one. For treating multivalued functions as functions, you have to treat them e.g. as set-valued functions or as tuple-valued functions.